# Android 4.4 keep booting into recovery mode

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, recovery-mode

I just bought this phone, [DOOGEE LEO DG280](http://www.doogeemobile.com/doogee-dg280.html), weeks later, it keep booting into recovery mode even though I restart the phone. I tried *reboot system now*, *apply update from sdcard*, *wipe data/factory reset* and *wipe cache partition*, but it doesn't work at all. I can't find solution on the internet that helps me. Any idea about this?